# Add image under the video with ffmepg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

I want to extend basic usage of watermark and put it under the video.
That means. I have input video 720x480 and image 720x20.
On output i want to have video 720x500 where video aspect is preserved and positioned to top and image is added to bottom.

input video

```
|--------------------------|
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|          720*480         |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
```

input image

```
|--------------------------|
|          720x20          |
|--------------------------|
```

output video

```
|--------------------------|
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|          720*480         |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
|          720x20          |
|--------------------------|
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you upload an image to see what you need?

Comment: @poor - put another way, he is saying he wants to append the image to the bottom of the video.  So the output should be the entire original video with the image below it. (The top edge of the image would be directly next to the bottom edge of the video.)

Comment: I added some visualization :)

Answer (score 7):

Use the [vstack filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack):

[image: hstack]

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex vstack output.mp4
```

If the image is not the same width as the video then resize it with the [scale filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:-1[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack" output.mp4
```

Comment: This generates a warning "More than 1000 frames duplicated" and takes forever to compete

Comment: @DineshSingh Need to see your command and the complete log. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's probably easier to *combine (stack) a full dimension background image (720x500px) with your video* in ffmpeg instead of adding the 20px footer to the video. You can simply use the `overlay filter` for this:

```
ffmpeg \
    -loop 1 -i 720x500.jpg \
    -i 720x480.mp4 \
    -filter_complex overlay=0:0 \
    -t 0:01.48 \ 
    out.m4v
```

**Note:** In this example you have to set the duration of your output video manually with `-t` parameter.

---

If you *don't want to specify the duration* you can use `shortest` flag within the filter if you use `-loop 1` as @LordNeckbeard mentioned in the comments below:

```
ffmpeg \
    -loop 1 -i 720x500.jpg \
    -i 720x480.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "overlay=0:0:shortest=1" \
    out.m4v
```

Comment: If you use `-loop 1` then you can set `shortest=1` in your overlay filter, as in `overlay=0:0:shortest=1`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for your ideas! I've updated my answer.